systemd: Service A starts before the service B even if service A is set After=B.service
I'm currently working with some systemd services, and here's the dependency scenario I'm trying to navigate:
A.service needs to consciously retry a few times when it fails.
C.service depends on A.service, but systemd doesn't handle service failure retries correctly if directly linked via Requires=A.service.
To address this dependency issue, I created B.service that gets activated via ExecStartPost by A.service. I've set C.service to start After=B.service.
However, I'm facing an unexpected behavior. C.service is also Wants by other services. It appears that sometimes C.service starts up before B.service, contrary to my After directive.
Could anyone help explain why C.service sometimes starts before B.service, despite clearly stating in the service definition file that it should start After=B.service?
Thank you in advance for your insights. Any suggestions or explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Please update this question to include a minimal reproducible example -- don't just describe your units in prose; show us actual service units so that we can see your exact configuration.
